# Testing trickplay on HLS version 4

Tags: iframe, streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm learning HTTP Live Streaming (HLS). In documment: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-07#section-3.3.12 , decription EXT-X-I-FRAMES-ONLY tag (hls v4) support trick-play feature.
I need have tools and samples streaming URL version 4 for my testing.

Please help me ! Tks !

I tried [iframe-playlist-generate tools](https://github.com/pbs/iframe-playlist-generator) for generate streaming, and test on vlc, but don't work.

Comment: streaming created by iframe-playlist-generate dont' play on vlc --> vlc don't support hls ver4 (or error streaming.) tks.

Comment: The PBS I-Frame Playlist generator byte-range samples work on my VLC. What version do you use?